# Format tree to print

Tags: java, recursion, tree

I am trying to visually format a tree (NOT A BST) so that it prints out appealing. I have written code to do so, and it compiles successfully as my tree has a maximum depth of 4. (I will work on making the dashes more attractive later). Here is what I have.

```
        String formatted = "";
    formatted += current.getName() +"\n";
    for (Node child: current.getChildren()) {  //figure out how to do this recursively
        formatted += "---"+child.getName() + "\n";
        if (child.getChildren() != null) {
            for (Node child2: child.getChildren()) {
                formatted += "------"+child2.getName() + "\n";
                if (child2.getChildren() != null) {
                    for (Node child3: child2.getChildren()){
                        formatted += "---------"+ child3.getName()+ "\n";
                        if (child3.getChildren() != null) {
                            for (Node child4: child3.getChildren()) {
                                formatted += "------------" + child4.getName()+ "\n";
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Obviously I want to find a way to do this recursively with any depth of tree but I am lost as how to do so. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried using bread-first search(BFS)?

Answer (score 0):

You would indeed need recursion. The trick is that you provide the indenting information to the recursive call, like a number of dashes to print before each line.

I will just use the same output format you were using:

```
String formatTree(Node root) {
    return formatTree(root, "");
}

String formatTree(Node current, String prefix) {
    String formatted = prefix + current.getName() + "\n";
    if (current.getChildren() != null) {
        // Any deeper node will have more dashes in front of it
        prefix += "---"; 
        for (Node child: current.getChildren()) {
            formatted += formatTree(child, prefix);
        }
    }
    return formatted;
}
```